# Не желаемое отображение анимации DoTween Unity 3D

Tags: unity3d

вообщем такая проблема, что мучался, мучался с камерой и получилось спавнить объекты/монеты там, где умирает собака. Проблема такая - в перемещении всё ок (см 1 скрин), делаю через дутвин, чтобы на разных экранах всё совпадало... Но с камеры это выглядит довольно странно (см 2 и 3 скрин, на 3 скрине сначала летит в угол, а потом к значку кристалла).

Кстати, если заменить трансформ на ректтрансформ, с основной камерой происходит какая-то суматоха. Кристаллы спавнятся то выше, то ниже собаки. Зависит от size орфографической камеры обрабатывающей ui. Хотел бы знать почему так...

А ещё, если вдруг понадобится, дам скрины двух камер. Первая камера - это основная (скрин 4), она рендерит окружение (не ui)

а вот ui камера (скрин 5), она висит на префабе.

```
код перемещения:
element.DOMove(endPoint, arrivalTime).SetUpdate(true);
```

[image: 1 скрин]

[image: 2 скрин]

[image: 3 скрин]

[image: 4 скрин]

[image: 5 скрин]